# Where does paging, sorting, etc go in repository pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

Where do we put the logic for paging and sorting data in an asp.net repository pattern project?

Should it go in the service layer or put it in the controller and have the controller directly call the repository? Controller -> Repository is shown [here](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/566_JQuery_jqGrid_Export_to_Excel_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx) for a jquery grid.

But unlike that article, my repository returns `IQueryable<datatype>`

Comment: The Linq .Skip() and .Take() are not enough? You can write an extension method GetPage(int index[, int pageSize = 20]) to make it complete.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It should go in the Repository if your Repository returns materialized sequences (`ICollection<T>`, `List<T>`), etc.

But if your returning `IQueryable<T>` (like i am), i hope you have a service layer mediating between your Controllers and Repository, which executes queries on the IQueryable and materialises them into concrete collections.

So, i would put the paging in the service layer.

Something like this:

```
public PagedList<T> Find(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, int pageNumber, pageSize)
{
   return repository
             .Find()
             .Where(predicate)
             .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

`.ToPagedList` can be an extension method that applies the paging you require and projects to a `PagedList<T>`.

There are many `PagedList<T>` implementations out there. I like [Rob Conery's one](http://www.squaredroot.com/2008/04/08/updated-pagedlist-class/). Has properties that your View requires, so you can bind to a `PagedList<T>` and create a HTML Helper to render out the page numbers very easily. The only problem with any paged list LINQ implementation is the `Count()` operation (for the number of records) needs to be done on the server and hence results in 2 round trips.

You don't want to be returning non-materialized queries to your View's, as IMO this breaks the MVC pattern.

Each time you go to a new page, call your service to retrieve the required result.

Comment: Returning non-materialized sequences is not advised. [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102149/should-a-repository-return-ienumerablet-iqueryablet-or-listt/46447615#46447615)

Answer (score 4):

- Sorting: should be done in the repository for large result sets; *may* be done inside the controller for small collections (i.e. without paging).
- Paging: IMO the repository should expose a way of returning *collection slices* (which is not exactly the same as *paging*). Meaning, there should be a way of asking the repository to return a query, *starting* at the index z and for the next y items. Then everything related to the particular page size (or page index) should be kept inside the controller. That way you can optimize data retrieval, but without coupling your model to a particular presentation requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting and paging are data functions.  It should go in the repository.

Comment: so my repository methods needs to take all these parameters?

Comment: I'd say so.  Whatever parameters are needed to delivery the correct subset of data.  Really this comes down to your philosophy about your architecture and how much fedelity you want to show to it.

Answer (score 2):

The repository should return a 'PageableResultSet', or something like that, which is responsible for the paging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe paging should go in the repository. See this answer I posted on another question.

[Repositories and persistence ignorance again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031437/repositories-and-persistence-ignorance-again/5031659#5031659)